# XCode library search path settings for static libraries (libssh2)

Tags: objective-c, static-libraries

I'm trying to use libssh2 using pre-build static libraries. I'm following instructions on this page:

http://code.google.com/p/ios-static-libraries/

This site explains I should configure my build settings as such:

`HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS[sdk=iphoneos4.2][arch=*] = $(inherited) "/path/to/iPhoneOS-4.2/include"
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS[sdk=iphonesimulator4.2][arch=*] = $(inherited) "/path/to/iPhoneSimulator-4.2/include"
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS[sdk=iphoneos4.2][arch=*] = $(inherited) "/path/to/iPhoneOS-4.2/lib"
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS[sdk=iphonesimulator4.2][arch=*] = $(inherited) "/path/to/iPhoneSimulator-4.2/lib"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -Wl,-search_paths_first -lz -lcrypto -liconv -lssl -lsasl2 -letpan -lgcrypt -lgpg-error -lssh2 -lcurl`

Where in XCode can I set these options? Do I have to edit a file manually? Or do I maybe need to use the XCode user interface to set these options?

Answer (score 2):

Add the lib path to your environment path DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just paste this in the buildSettings part for your configurations. Open up your project's project.pbxproj file (it's inside the xcodeproj bundle) in your favorite text editor and search for buildSettings. You will see a section for each of your configurations as defined in XCode.

A prettier way of doing this would be through the build settings for your project which you can access by right-clicking your project in the navigator and clicking 'Get Info'. There you can set these build settings under 'Build', but I guess that copy-paste is easier in this case.

<sub>Is this an interview question? ;-)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project->Edit Project Settings to open the build settings window.  Select the build tab.

In the build settings window, select the setting you want to modify (like "Library search paths").  Then click the gear in the lower left, and select "Add Build Setting Condition."  Then you can add a value that applies only to iOS Simulator builds, and a second build setting condition to apply only to device builds.

Answer (score 0):

Some time you want search path on Xcode, just use this keyword

$(SRCROOT)/../**.a

If you more static files, like this:

"$(SRCROOT)/../**.a" "$(SRCROOT)/../**.a"